# WP7 stream audio with dynamic URI

Tags: windows-phone-7, dynamic, background, agent

I used `BackgroundAudioPlayer` to play mp3 from internet and I know that background audio agent automatically streams the mp3

Does audio agent plays after completely streams the mp3 ?

If the mp3 URI is dynamic, how to play it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a continuous audio stream, then the background audio agent will continue playing it. If it is a single file, the playback will stop on completion.

Also, there is no way you can specify a dynamic URL. There is the core location that you specify for the stream that has to be adjusted in-app.

Comment: thanks. Does the audio agent both play and stream simultaneously? I notice there is BufferingStopped event